# AdWords ; The oauth client was not found

Tags: python, oauth, google-ads-api, google-data-api

I'm currently trying to import adwords data using the client library on python.

For this I created an account manager and I asked for a developer token to use API Adwords. Until this one is approved I try to test it on test accounts. So I created a test manager account under which I created a test client account.

I logged in with my account manager (the real not the test account) and I asked for OAuth2 ID that I got. I also had the "refresh token".

Is this the right approach ?

I've completed the googleads.yaml (AdWords configuration) file by adding
The oAuth2 IDs, the refresh token, and the client test account ID.

But when I run a file I get the error message: ''The oAuth2 client was not found''. As you can see on the screenshot.

So anyone knows what's happen?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDwO4.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Refresh Token for [test AdWords account](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts) you need login via your **another** Google account for testing purpose.

When you want use real/production account you need generate another Refresh Token (after login real manager account).